# Conditional Probability Matrix in Python for dynamic values

Tags: python, probability, bayesian

I need to calculate and store a Conditional Probability Table (for a Bayesian Network) which is an extract from a Matrix whose input will be N (number of unique Thresholds for each node) and T(number of parents a node can have). The value of T usually ranges from 1 to 10 & range for N is usually from 3 to 7.

Example,

```
If N = 5, and T = 1 the values will be 5^1=5
if N = 5, and T = 2 the values will be 5^2 = 25
if N = 5, and T = 3 the values will be 5^3 = 125
(and so on).
```

The value of N can also change , but I'm keeping the example simple.

The output required is :
(for T=1 & N=5 , output should be 5^1=5 ,that is a 1*5 matrix 
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] ):

```
T_Id    Cell_Id Probability
T001        1       0.2
T001        2       0.2
T001        3       0.2
T001        4       0.2
T001        5       0.2
```

(for T=2 & N=5 , output should be 5^2=25 ,that is a 5*5 matrix) :

```
T_Id    Cell_Id Probability
T002        1   0.732292842
T002        2   0.232364214
T002        3   0.033319518
T002        4   0.001977041
T002        5   4.63852E-05
T002        6   0.188558672
T002        7   0.59424024
T002        8   0.188558672
T002        9   0.027038088
T002        10  0.001604327
T002        11  0.026367464
T002        12  0.183881865
T002        13  0.579501342
T002        14  0.183881865
T002        15  0.026367464
T002        16  0.001604327
T002        17  0.027038088
T002        18  0.188558672
T002        19  0.59424024
T002        20  0.188558672
T002        21  4.63852E-05
T002        22  0.001977041
T002        23  0.033319518
T002        24  0.232364214
T002        25  0.732292842
```

Similarly for T=3 & N=5 , output should be 5^3=125, and so on....

How can this be achieved in Python keeping scalability for combination of T & N in mind?

P.S. : A similar functionality can be achieved using the below code, but it uses RANDOM values as input, can the below code be modified to achieve the results as shown above ?

```
import random

precision = 1000

def f(n) :
    matrix = []
    for l in range(n) :
        lineLst = []
        sum = 0
        crtPrec = precision
        for i in range(n-1) :
            val = random.randrange(crtPrec)
            sum += val
            lineLst.append(float(val)/precision)
            crtPrec -= val
        lineLst.append(float(precision - sum)/precision)
        matrix.append(lineLst)
    return matrix

matrix = f(5)
print matrix
```

Sample Output from above :

```
[[0.64, 0.229, 0.043, 0.034, 0.054], 
[0.847, 0.04, 0.068, 0.04, 0.005], 
[0.758, 0.148, 0.006, 0.027, 0.061], 
[0.159, 0.477, 0.329, 0.023, 0.012], 
[0.817, 0.146, 0.026, 0.01, 0.001]]
```

Expected output (if N=5, that is f(5)) :

```
[[0.7322, 0.2323, 0.0333, 0.0019, 4.63852E-05], 
    [0.1885, 0.5942, 0.1885, 0.0270, 0.0016], 
    [0.0263, 0.1838, 0.5795, 0.1838, 0.0263], 
    [0.0016, 0.0270, 0.1885, 0.5942, 0.1885], 
    [4.63852E-05, 0.0019, 0.0333, 0.2323, 0.7322]]
```

Comment: Where do the values in the probability column come from in the real case?

Comment: how should the array look like at 5^3 = 125 ?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe - that is being calculated on basis of a Gaussian Normal distribution , for example a 5*5 matrix will have 25 values with the diagonal elements being highest values.

Comment: @Moritz - the array will be a 3D having 125 elements. so I assume it will be a list of lists.

Comment: But how do you determine the shape ?

Comment: What's your actual question? What are the inputs? How do you actually calculate the outputs from them? Why are you worried about scalability?

Comment: @ShankarPandey If your variables are actually Gaussian, you may be better off just using them as continuous variables, instead of discretizing them. If all variables are Gaussian or discrete (with only discrete parents of Gaussian, or discrete/discrete or Gaussian/Gausian, and not Gaussian parents of discrete), then exact results are known.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe - what I want is to compute a multivariate normal distribution p for values which are given to it.
How its supposed to work is :
1. Find the number of parent nodes for a child node. (variable T in above example)
2. Find the  multivariate distribution values (variable N in above example)
3. calculate a N*N matrix with multivariate normal distribution values (row values summing upto 1).

Comment: @AndrewJaffe -
4. calculation is done on basis of indexes of rows/columns , that is, the diagonal values will have maximum values as compared to others.
and other values will be in decreasing order.
5. example of calculation :
row-1,col-1 (1-1) has difference of 0, so will have largest value and row-1,col-5 (1-5) has maximum difference so will have least value

I hope this helps, i understand that the requirement might sound clumsy, apologies but I tried to explain to the best of my knowledge :)